# LoadLibrary in C

Tags: c, loadlibrary

I have a DLL generated in Matlab by using LCC compiler and I want to call a function from this DLL. The name of DLL is fcn_acDklGenerator and the name of function is also fcn_acDklGenerator, therefore, I wrote the below code but it fails in loading library.

```
char* libName = "\\fcn_acDklGenerator.dll";
TCHAR libFullPath[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, libFullPath);
strcat_s(libFullPath, sizeof libFullPath, libName);
HMODULE matlab = LoadLibrary(libFullPath);
```

The output of the LoadLibrary is NULL while I have cheked the libFullPath value and I am sure that the DLL is located at that path.

Comment: LoadLibrary() has multiple reasons to return NULL, the path is only one possible failure mode.  The next likely one is this DLL having dependencies that cannot be found.  Get ahead with GetLastError() to obtain the error code, a tool like Dumpbin.exe to see dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many causes and many techniques for tracking them down, so here's a Community Wiki answer that hopefully can help many people facing DLL loading problems:

Reasons a LoadLibrary can fail:

- The .dll file is not found, not readable, or not executable.  (This can get complicated with varying search path rules, file system redirection, another DLL of the same name already loaded into the process, SxS cache, ACLs, exclusive sharing, being marked for deletion, interference from malware protection tools, etc.)
- The DLL is 64-bit and you're trying to load it into a 32-bit process, or vice versa.
- The DLL depends (directly or indirectly) on another DLL that fails to load.  (In other words, this list might need to be applied recursively.)
- There is no reasonable address range available for the DLL (extremely unlikely).
- DllMain (or equivalent function of another name) uses the wrong calling convention.
- DLLMain returns an error.
- DllMain creates a deadlock.  While that usually results in a hang, it's conceivable that in some cases the loader might detect it and just fail the load.

Techniques for diagnosing a particular instance:

- Checking [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) immediately after a failed call to LoadLibrary usually helps narrow down the possibilities.
- Depending on the setting of [SetErrorMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) for the process, you may also glean some information from dialogs that appear.
- Stepping over the LoadLibrary call in a debugger, like Visual Studio, can give hints in the debug output windows, as you may see which other DLLs are loading along with the one you requested.
- You can also use a tool like Sysinternals' PROCMON to see which paths are actually being searched, what type of I/O error a failed attempt to open a file is getting, etc.
- You can temporarily replace a complex DllMain with a trivial one to determine whether the complex DllMain is causing the failure.

Tools like dumpbin and DependencyWalker can answer questions about bitness, whether there's a DllMain exported, and what other DLLs are required.

Answer (score -1):

Before you call LoadLibrary place checking code:

`if ( GetFileAttributes(libFullPath) == 0xFFFFFFFF )
{
   //Something went wrong
   //print error code for GetLatError()
}`

After you call LoadLibrary place checking code:

`if ( matlab == NULL )
{
   //Something went wrong
   //print error code for GetLatError()
}`